# need to convert jpg or jpeg/png/bmp to WSQ in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

Is there any way to convert a bmp/jpg/png image to WSQ without losing the quality in C#? Using Image class we can convert bmp/jpg but the quality for fingerprint output image is very poor. Can we gain the quality level as good as an image converted?